# *this vs this in C++

Tags: c++, this

I understand what `this` does, but what is the difference between `*this` and `this`?

Yes, I have Googled and read over `*this` in my text book, but I just don't get it...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, and `*this` is a dereferenced pointer.

If you had a function that returned `this`, it would be a pointer to the current object, while a function that returned `*this` would be a "clone" of the current object, allocated on the stack -- *unless* you have specified the return type of the method to return a reference.

A simple program that shows the difference between operating on copies and references:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {
            this->value = 0;
        }

        Foo get_copy()
        {
            return *this;
        }

        Foo& get_copy_as_reference()
        {
            return *this;
        }

        Foo* get_pointer()
        {
            return this;
        }

        void increment()
        {
            this->value++;
        }

        void print_value()
        {
            std::cout << this->value << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        int value;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_copy().increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_copy_as_reference().increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_pointer()->increment();
    foo.print_value();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
3
```

You can see that when we operate on a *copy* of our local object, the changes don't persist (because it's a different object entirely), but operating on a reference or pointer *does* persist the changes.

Comment: I'm validating here: returning *this doesn't return the reference of the object but a copy of the object?

Comment: You are right to ask. *this in fact returns a reference to the object. For example if you overload the [] operator in your class you can inside the class use (*this)[] instead of operator[].

Comment: Mark, your example is misleading. Try Foo& get_copy() { return *this; }. Then you see that in fact *this is a REFERENCE.

Comment: @ypnos: I see what you mean and I have clarified my answer to differentiate between returning `*this` as a copy and as a reference.

Comment: @ypnos: *this being a dereferenced pointer or a reference has nothing to do with that. `Foo & get_copy() { return *this; }` will return a reference, since you tell it to (by declaring Foo &). And `Foo get_copy() { return *this; }` will return a copy of the object, as with any other type.

Comment: To be more precise, the dereference of a pointer results in an *lvalue* that refers to the object. Since it is an lvalue, you can assign it to a reference variable and get a reference to it; or you can assign it to a variable of the object's type and get a copy, or you can do `&` on it to get the pointer again.

Comment: @MarkRushakoff: so, when we overload = (assignment) operator it should return reference to clone of the object. Right?

Answer (score 2):

##### Case 1

[`this`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.this) is a pointer to an object of a class, on which the non-static member function was called. Moreover, when used as an expression the **value-category** of `this` is ***prvalue***.

When we call a **non-static member function** on an object of the class, the address of that object is **implicitly** passed as the first argument of that member function. This is possible because every non-static member function has an implicit parameter named `this` which is of type `X*` for a nonconst member function and `const X*` for a const member function, where `X` is some class.

##### Case 2

When we apply `*` on `this` the result is the object to which the pointer `this` was pointing. We are basically **dereferencing** the `this` pointer. That is, `*this` gives us the object to which the pointer `this` points. In other words, we get the object on which we called the non-static member function.

Moreover, when used as an expression the value category of `*this` is ***lvalue***. Also, note that

> The type of an expression is **never** a reference.

Note that **lvalue expression** is different from **lvalue reference**. The answer by *Marcelo Cantos* and comment by *cigien* seems to be confusion these two concepts.

##### Summary

| `this` | `*this` |
| --- | --- |
| Pointer to an object of a class on which the non-static member function was called. | Result of dereferencing the `this` pointer. The result is the actual object on which the non-static member function was called. |
| prvalue-expression | lvalue-expression |

Answer (score -8):

There is no real difference, `this->foo()` is the same as `(*this).foo()`.

Comment: ahh yes, guess i should have thrown that in the compiler first to verify :)