# C++ pointer and address clarification in relation to the current object

Tags: c++, pointers

So far to my understanding, when defining a pointer variable, we are allocating space in RAM for that variable.

```
int *p;
```

Would define a space in RAM. Then we assign a memory address to that pointer using `&variable'.

I'm looking over at an example on: [*this vs this in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750316/this-vs-this-in-c)
The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {
            this->value = 0;
        }

        Foo get_copy()
        {
            return *this;
        }

        Foo& get_copy_as_reference()
        {
            return *this;
        }

        Foo* get_pointer()
        {
            return this;
        }

        void increment()
        {
            this->value++;
        }

        void print_value()
        {
            std::cout << this->value << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        int value;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_copy().increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_copy_as_reference().increment();
    foo.print_value();

    foo.get_pointer()->increment();
    foo.print_value();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what the purpose of putting the `*` operator in front `Foo* get_copy()` and `Foo* get_pointer()` does. Why do I get an error if I removed the `*` from the `Foo*` functions while returning `this` not `*this`?

edit:

Also, why is:

```
foo.get_copy().increment();
foo.print_value();
```

yielding 1 not 2?

Comment: the return type for `get_copy` is wrong. It should return by value, not pointer - `Foo get_copy()`

Comment: Foo get_copy yields an error unless `this` is changed to `*this`.

Comment: `*this` is exactly what it's supposed to be. Look at the original source. You copied it wrong.

Comment: Oh whoops, I copied my modified version. Edited. So `this` is a pointer by nature, though deferenced. A pointer can only be deferenced if it has a pointee, and that pointee is the current object. When we dereference a pointer, we are changing the state of the current object being pointed to, aka the pointee. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Ok, my turn to confuse. A pointer variable should only be dereferenced if it contains a valid pointer value. A valid pointer value points to a living object. When you dereference a pointer you do not change the objects state **until** you call a mutating member function or directly modify a member variable. Generally speaking ;)

Comment: You are not changing any objects by using `*`. See my answer below for the 2 meanings of `*`.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand what the purpose of putting the `*` operator in front `Foo* get_copy()` and `Foo* get_pointer()` does

```
Foo* get_pointer()
```

`Foo*` is a *pointer* that points to `Foo` object.

`this` is also a pointer that implicitly bind to the calling object of the member function. That's why the return type of those functions are `Foo*` not `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`this`, is always a pointer in C++, though you don't mention it explicitly anywhere. So while returning a this pointer, should use `Foo*`

`this` is actually an implicit object passed during function call, which is a pointer to the object which calls the function

Comment: @eveo `this` isn't a variable.  It's an expression, and is an rvalue, so it doesn't have an address (and it cannot be modified).  The _type_ of the expression `this` is a pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is part of the type.  So `int` means type `int`, and
`int*` type pointer to `int`.  If the function returns pointer
to int, it is `int* foo()`, and if it retu rns a pointer to
`Foo`, it is `Foo* Foo::get_pointer()`.

The definition reserves space for the defined *object*.  A
declaration doesn't reserve any space, and definitions of things
that aren't objects (e.g. references or functions) don't reserve
any space either, at least not that you can see.  (Obviously, a
function does exist somewhere in memory, and in many cases, the
compiler will need space as well for its implementation of a
reference.  But they are invisible within the scope of C++.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have changed the code from the example that you refer to so that `get_copy()` no longer returns a copy.

There are 2 ways of using `*` in your code example. One is for type declaration and the other is the dereferencing operator.

First the type declarations:

`int *p` means declaring `p` as a variable of type "pointer to an int".

`Foo *get_pointer()` means that the function `get_pointer` will return a value of type "pointer to a Foo object".

Now the dereferencing:

`*p` means "the value that p points to".

```
int a = 42; 
int *p;  // p is of type "pointer to an int"
p = &a;  // set p to the address of a (p now "points to" a)

a = 117;  // change the value of a
int x = *p; // set x to the value that p points to (which is a) - x will be 117
```

`this` is just a pointer to the object. `*this` means "the object that this points to". In your example `this` is of type `Foo*` (pointer to a Foo object) while `*this` is of type `Foo` (a Foo object).

Answer (score -1):

`"this" is a pointer`. 
you want to return a pointer to the instance (a specific allocated object).

```
 Foo* get_pointer(){
            return this;
        }
```

or you want to return a pointer to the copy, allocate a new object.

```
//need to implement the copy here
       Foo* get_copy(){
            return this;
        }
```

and not to the reference (address of the instance). this is why you need to return the pointer.

Comment: You are not returning a pointer to a copy you are returning a pointer to the current object. No copy has been made. It should be `Foo get_copy() { return *this; }` if you want to return a copy or instantiate one in dynamic storage and return a pointer to it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you are right, I meant that you need yo implement the copy.