# checking what I am passing and returning in a overload operator

Tags: c++

First, I am using as reference [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2750322/4451521) on `this` and `*this`.

Say I have a class:

```cpp
class myclass{
    
    myclass& dosomething(){
        // do something here
        return *this;  //According to the referenced answer I am returning the same object
    }
    
    myclass& operator<<(myclass &mc){
        return mc;   // HERE, am I returning the same object??
    }    
};

int main(){
    myclass myobject;
    myobject << myobject.dosomething();    
}
```

My question is, in the overload operator, I am passing a reference as aan argument, right? And I am returning the same object, is this correct?

Comment: If `x` and `y` are both `myclass`, do you want `x << y` to evaluate to `x` or `y`?

Comment: `myclass myobject();` here you're defining `myobject` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns a `myclass`. You want to do this instead: `myclass myobject;`

Comment: @Kevin corrected thanks

Comment: `myclass& myclass::operator<<(myclass &mc)` could be written as free operator: `myclass& operator<<(myclass& mcL, myclass& mcR)`. As you have implemented the former, the latter would have to do `return mcR;`. (With the former doing `return *this` instead, the latter had to `return mcL;`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think `y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the same reference that is passed as parameter. This is ok-ish, but only if thats what you want. For method chaining you typically do return `*this`.

Consider the following to see the difference:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

struct myclass {
   int value;
   myclass& operator<<(myclass &mc) {
       std::cout << value << " << " << mc.value << "\n";
       return mc;
   }

   myclass& operator>>(myclass& mc){
       std::cout << value << " >> " << mc.value << "\n";
       return *this;
   }

};

int main(){
     myclass m1{1},m2{2},m3{3};
     m1 << m2 << m3;
     std::cout << "\n";
     m1 >> m2 >> m3;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/q4orh813T):

```
1 << 2
2 << 3

1 >> 2
1 >> 3
```

Maybe it also helps to realize that the two lines can also be written as:

```
 m1.operator<<(m2).operator<<(m3);
 m1.operator>>(m2).operator>>(m3);
```

Usually one expects that `m1 >> m2 >> m3;` resolves to chained calls on `m1`, ie first `m1 >> m2` then `m1 >> m3`.

Only when it is clear from context and semantics of `myclass` you should make `m1 << m2 << m3;` call first `m1 << m2` and then `m2 << m3`.

Operator overloading is very permissive, you can do very weird things if you like, but it might lead to surprises when the user expects your `operator<<` to chain as usual.